# UIImagePickerController allowsEditing = YES not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        [actionSheet removeFromSuperview];
    }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

can't drag the photo when i take a picture,but photos in `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` can edit

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. its working for me in front and rear camera mode.

UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;

```
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

        }

    }
```